# Moxy/JAXB/Jersey marshal POJO to JSON when POJO already has a JSON String field

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have an POJO that I'd like to return from a rest method as JSON.   One field in the POJO is string that is already formatted in JSON.   When this method is marshaled via JAXB/MOXY, the entire value is quoted and all internal quotes are escaped.

Is there any way to tell JAXB/MOXY to use this field as a raw/unformatted value instead of processing it as a normal string?

Thanks.